# Why can't I use nested yield in for..in loop in Redux-Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So I have `tasks` object with ids and values. With for in loop I want to read 'members' property. If it exist, and first element of array `!=='all'` I want to make request to firebase for read document by given id. But I cant use **`yield`**, there is error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/containers/modules/Tasks/store/sagas/tasksSagas.js
  Line 27:  Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'yield'
```

Why am I getting it? I can't use nested yields?

```
//Fetching users for tasks
  for (const task in tasks) {
    if (tasks[task].hasOwnProperty('members')) {
      if (tasks[task].members[0]==='all'){
        tasks[task].fetchedMembers = ['all']
      }
      else {
        const fetchedMembers = tasks[task].members.map(member => {
          const user = yield db.collection('users').doc(member).get()
          const userData = user.data()
          return {
            uid: member,
            ...userData
          }
        })
        tasks[task].fetchedMembers = fetchedMembers
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) does what you think it does. You probably want `await`, in which case your `map` function needs to use `async`.

Comment: are you in a generator function? are you sure you are not looking at async / await?

Comment: i have created saga. there is allot of async requests will be

Answer (score 2):

```
const fetchedMembers = tasks[task].members.map(member => {
  const user = yield db.collection('users').doc(member).get()
  const userData = user.data()
  return {
    uid: member,
    ...userData
  }
})
```

The function you pass to `.map` is not a generator function, so you can't use `yield` in it. And it can't be a generator function, since `map` knows nothing about generators or sagas.

One option is to create an array of promises, and then yield that (either wrapped in Promise.all, or redux-saga's all effect):

```
const promises = tasks[task].members.map(member => {
  return db.collection('users').doc(member).get();
})

const members = yield all(promises);
const fetchedMembers = members.map(user => {
  const userdata = user.data();
  return {
    uid: member,
    ...userData;
  }
);
```

Another option is to write a mini-saga you want to do for each member, and then create an array of call effects, then yield all of those:

```
const callEffects = tasks[task].members.map(member => {
  return call(function* () {
    const user = yield db.collection('users').doc(member).get()
    const userData = user.data()
    return {
      uid: member,
      ...userData
    }
  });
})

const fetchedMembers = yield all(callEffects);
```