# Resolve promise(s) inside map of redux saga generator

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, es6-promise, redux-saga

I have a generator where I update an object. Here I need to call multiple functions that return promises so I use yield all and (definite pun intended) all is good. Something like this:

```
function* updateTheThing() {
  ...
  const [resultA, resultB, resultC] = yield all([funcA(), funcB(), funcC()]);
  ...
}
```

This works for updating a single item but I want to update an array of items. My thought was to use map and map over the items but the problem is that I cannot yield inside the map. I've done something similar before when all I needed to do was call some API like this:

```
const promises = things.map(thing => { 
  return call(api.someEndpoint);
});

const data = yield all(promises);
```

But I cannot do that here as I am not using redux saga's call. My code right now is like this, but it is not working:

```
function* updateAllTheThings() {
  try {
    const updatedThings = things.map(thing => {
      const resultA = funcA();  // resultA is a promise
      const resultB = funcB();  // resultB is a promise
      const resultC = funcC();  // resutlC is a promise
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error updating all the things: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

resultA, resultB and resultC are promises but I need the resolved value as I need to use it further down INSIDE the map statement.

Maybe my approach to this is wrong but I am stumped. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright with the help of the answer from Nicolas Tower in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207095/why-cant-i-use-nested-yield-in-for-in-loop-in-redux-saga) I was able to re-think and re-write my code to work as expected. I will add my solution here in case someone finds it helpful.

So the part of the question that I decided to use was to, in their words, create a mini saga, so my code is now like this:

```
function* updateAllTheThings() {
  try {
    const promisedThings = things.map(thing => {
      return call (function* () {
        const resultA = funcA();  // resultA is a promise
        const resultB = funcB();  // resultB is a promise
        const resultC = funcC();  // resutlC is a promise
      });
    });
    const updatedThings = yield all(promisedThings);
    ... 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error updating all the things: ${error}`);
  }
}
```